# can't get gmail user displayname via firebase3 login in Ionic platform

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on google auth with firebase signinwithcredential. I first used cordovaoath to get the id token and sign it in with firebase. I specifically indicated in my code that I would like to get the displayName, but it always come back null. I was wondering anyone have faced the same problem?

[image]

```
   this.loginWithGoogle = function loginWithGoogle() {
    $cordovaOauth.google("mygoogleclient id here", ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]).then(function (result) {
        // "email", "profile",
        console.log("first come here to oath");
        console.log("Response Object -> " + JSON.stringify(result));

        var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (firebaseUser) {

            unsubscribe();
            // Check if we are already signed-in Firebase with the correct user.
            // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
            var credential='';
             credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                result.id_token);

            // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
            firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(function (error) {

                // Handle Errors here.
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                // The email of the user's account used.

                var email = error.email;
                // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
                var credential = error.credential;
            });
        });


    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error -> " + error);
    });




};
```

sreenshot of my returned result

[image]

Comment: The gmail address is in your screenshots and verified. What's the problem?

Comment: I want to also get the displayName, but the displayName is always null even though I specifically added the scope for profile.Thanks!

Comment: Interesting: I get the display name, even without specifying any additional scope: `displayName:"Frank van Puffelen"`

Comment: Thanks for checking! Frank! Did you also used signInWithCredential and cordovaoath? If not, do you mind share with me how you got it to work? Thanks!

Comment: I used the plain JavaScript API: `auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())`. Where does `$cordovaOauth` come from? It's up to each provider to determine what properties it exposes.

Comment: It works fine with signinwithpopup, but since I am using Ionic platform and it is not supported by Firebase, my only choice is using a plugin and signinwithcredential. Thanks thou! Frank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should request an access token, and not an ID token, if you are requesting additional scopes.

To fix your code, change this line:

```
var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                            null, result.access_token); // <- access_token
```